# Google Watermark not showing in custom search box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search, adsense

I'm using this code:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/search" id="cse-search-box-alt"> 
  <div> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-xx" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" /> 
    <input type="text" name="q" size="13" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" /> 
  </div> 
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box-alt&lang=en"></script>
```

I'm putting it on a WP site, I tried changing the id, but the watermark is still not showing on the searchbox. 
Appreciate your help on this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the **LookAndFeel** element, and the **googlebranding** attribute. 
Google have this well documented here, https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ui_xml

Comment: Thanks! But I have to use that html code. I'm not sure how to insert the Look and Feel attribute to it.

Comment: actually I've read about this on other sites, it seems to be a known issue at present: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/BcKzBo6ycRo/I-_VfKSPhGAJ

Comment: Hi Frank C! I followed the solution posted on that forum, and it worked!! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=en"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cse.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=en"></script>
```

And watermark should show. Seems to be a bug, which they will probably fix soon.